# If i wanted to make a button, open/switch to another webview how would i go on about that?

Tags: android, xml, webview

I'm new to coding, I currently have a webview displaying a page and buttons at the bottom such  as ;

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webview2"
        android:text="Facebook" />
```

How would I get this to view facebook?

Answer (score 0):

You need a OnClickListener for your Button e.g. [Developer Guide for Button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something in response to button click
    }
});
```

After this you also need a WebView item on your layout e.g. [Developer Guide for WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Same as Button for the WebView

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

You have to do your job and read yourself into such things. The keywords are OnClickListener,WebView,WebViewClient(for facebook).